# When does the view controller get redrawn or subviews get re-laid when app is coming back to foreground

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I created Twitter-based paging for my app. Everything works perfectly, but for some reason when I'm on the second page, press the home button out of the app, then press the app icon to get back in, the page offsets 20 pixels down.

I have no idea where this is happening, and how to mitigate this issue.

I'm mainly hoping there is somewhere in the iOS lifecycle where I could mitigate this, but I have no idea where.

I'd done `println` in many lifecycle functions including in my MainViewController which holds my two pages, the actual page, and the appDelegate.

Only in the appDelegate did I get any action. This was at `enteringForeground` which is supposed to happen.

I'm thinking of just offsetting by `-20 dy` when I come enter back via the enteringForeground, but I'm not sure how.

Here is a video depicting the issue: https://vid.me/iqJ9

**Update:** Turns out, this only happens when the user is already logged in and bypasses the LoginRegisterViewController. When a user is already logged in, I check via the code below in my `AppDelegate` and then skip the LoginRegisterViewController all together and show the MainViewController. When the user logs in via the LoginRegisterViewController and gets sent to MainViewController, this issue does not happen. I must be doing something wrong in the code below:

My App Delegate currently has this in it

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("auth_token") != nil {

            var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

            self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainViewController") as? MainViewController
            self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }

        return true

    }

    ....

}
```

Comment: Check `viewWillAppear` and your rotation methods, all of which may get called when the app returns. Log your the frames of your views when this happens to see when it changes.

Comment: @AaronBrager I have tried printlning in my viewWillAppears and they don't get called

Comment: If they don't get called then the view controller isn't appearing.

Comment: How is that possible? What am I looking at then?

Comment: A different view controller maybe? Or your method signature is wrong? Or your view hierarchy is set up incorrectly? Hard to say, but `viewWillAppear` will definitely get called when you switch to your app.

Comment: Can you post a sample app that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I posted what my App Delegate currently has in it. Basically, a check to see if someone is already logged in, and if so, then to not bring up the LoginRegisterViewController, but MainViewController instead.

Comment: @AaronBrager Turns out I think I did something wrong with my bringing in the MainViewController instead of LoginRegisterViewController... When I get to the MainViewController from the LoginRegisterViewController, then it doesn't happen. It only happens when I get there from the MainViewController (bypassing the loginRegisterViewController). The code is edited in

Comment: If your view controller is already presented when it goes to background, when coming back to foreground, viewWillAppear: won't get called. There must be something else you're doing that could prevent this, but if you want to go to the path of finding out when the app comes to the foreground again, you can observe for UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification using NSNotificationCenter.

Comment: @rocir I just solved it, or rather, worked around it by letting iOS delegate the windows. I now do my check for if a user is logged in in the LoginRegisterViewController, and I made a custom segue such that it shows no animation, so you won't know you were in the LoginRegisterViewController.

Comment: That being said, I do get this called twice: "Warning: Attempt to present <Gate.MainViewController: 0x7fe759429a40> on <Gate.LoginRegisterViewController: 0x7fe7595ab280> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
" which is unfortunate.

Comment: Please do not store an auth token in `NSUserDefaults`. That is a pointless, significant security risk. Please use the keychain.

Comment: Noted and fixed. Didn't realize that. I was just using it as a SharedPreferences (Android) equivalent.